# MongoDB --Aggregate the record count based on last 30 days

Tags: mongodb, match

Hi I am trying to get the aggregated count for the last 30 days of records.

To achieve this I am using the below `$match` condition in **Mongo** aggregation pipeline

```
$match
{
"stageStartDate":{$gt: [new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)]}
}
```

> Error on Execution: Invalid Date Format at ISODate()

Please help me in solving this. I can't use Javascript, as I am directly calling this query in Jaspersoft reports.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, just create a new date object from milliseconds difference

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {stageStartDate: {$gt: new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30))}}}]);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. I posted below the exception I get after trying this approach. I appreciate if you can help me in figuring this out